# Org-babel and anaconda-mode in src blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python, anaconda-mode

I practice python literate programming with tangling to generate a full project structure. There are dependencies between modules and packages, and so I will say in the `C-c '`:

```
#+begin_src python tangle: "src/foo/bar.py"
  def do_stuff():
      pass
#+end_src

#+begin_src python tangle: "src/foo/baz.py"
  from foo.bar import do_stuff
#+end_src
```

And so the project structure looks like this (omitting init.py):

- project.org

  - src

    - foo

      - bar.py
      - baz.py

But the `C-c '` edit buffer is in the same directory as project.org so anaconda-mode won't recognize the import statement. All code is run from the tangled source rather than within the project.org buffer.

I have the tangle file names and dirs as elisp variables. It would be nice if I could have anaconda completion on project source code.

Can I point anaconda-mode to look from within the tangle, ie. source code file path?